# connecting Darwin Caldav to thunderbird calendar

Tags: thunderbird, caldav, darwin

I am a newbie to caldav and server setups and need some specific, detailed help from anyone who knows Darwin caldav.

I installed Darwin caldav server onto my iMac w/ Maverick.  I have it up and running in the background.  After some fiddling I connected iCal and my iphone to it and they are exchanging info regularly.

I am now trying to connect my Thunderbird calendar to it.  When creating the connection, Thunderbird calls for Location.  No matter what I enter (comp ip with portals, http foramt of same) Thunderbird won't connect.

I was able to connect through iCal, entering the computer's ip address, 192.168.1.19, but in Thunderbird this address doesn't work.  I enter it as a web location, http://192.168.1.19, but still no connection.

Would someone explain how Darwin caldav is spoken to, connected to, what Thunderbird is looking for as far as location, and what I should be entering?  As I said, I'm a newbie to this some I would appreciate some explanation of why I would enter things as given, not just what to enter.

Also, while installing Darwin caldav I read that once installed I would connect using a web browser.  Is there a separate way to connect to D-caldav directly using some kind of built in gui, or was this just a reference to connecting to it as I am already doing, using a calendar and a web connection?

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird doesnt seem to support collection discovery (calendar-home), so it needs to be pointed directly to a calendar collection.

According to some other guidelines (e.g. here: http://sabre.io/dav/clients/thunderbird/ or http://oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=SetUpThunderbirdLightningCalDAVClient you need to find out for your server the absolute url to an calendar instead pointing like other clients to the root folder of the server.

```
http(s)://[domain]/[pathtocalendarfolders]/[username]/[calendarname]/
```

Hope this helps a little bit.

Best Regards, Hilmar